# Removing duplicate array elements with order preserved

Tags: collections, smalltalk, pharo

Is there a standard method for removing duplicate entries in an array, but preserving the order?

e.g.

```
#(c a b a a b) withoutDuplicates "-> #(c a b)"
```

I used to use `removeDuplicates`, but apparently that's an extension method added by Roassal (so I cannot always use it)

Written by hand, the best solution (I have) is

```
a := #(c a b a a b).
d := OrderedDictionary new.
a do: [ :each | d at: each put: true ].
d keys. "-> #(c a b)"
```

But is there a standard way?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks very good to me. Here is another one:

```
withoutDuplicates
  | visited |
  visited := Set new.
  ^self select: [:element | 
    (visited includes: element) not
      ifTrue: [visited add: element];
      yourself]
```

This one is more verbose but uses (only) one additional collection: the `visited` set. An `OrderedDictionary`, on the other hand, has two internal collections a `Dictionary` and the sequence of `orderedKeys`. If you are not concerned with space I would suggest using your solution.

As an aside note I would say that the use of `#yourself` here is a bit unusual. It follows the pattern:

```
^boolean ifTrue: [self doThis]; yourself
```

Which has a side effect (`self doThis`) when `boolean` is `true` and answers with `boolean` in either case. Most people would write it as:

```
boolean ifTrue: [self doThis].
^boolean
```

but this requires the addition of a block temporary because in our case `boolean` refers to the expression `(visited includes: element) not` which we shouldn't repeat.

---

**OR...**

... you could take this opportunity to implement `OrderedSet` in Pharo...

---

Answer (score 1):

Same as yours but shorter in terms of text to type, not performance.

```
(#(c a f b c a d c a e f f) collect: [ :e | e -> true ]) asOrderedDictionary keys
```

Comment: `(#(a b c c b d) collect: [:e | e -> true] into: OrderedDictionary new) keys` saves one transient collection.